# need guidance my vignette code in Jython/Python

Tags: python, jes

i'm having trouble with having my CGI picture and vignette profile image going together to make a vignette picture where the picture is slightly darker around the edges of the picture without compromising the image anywhere else, i am getting everything so far that i think is right but my picture is showing up dark in the middle instead of showing the image normal but with slightly darker colored edges.

this is what i have currently:

```
def main(): 
inputPic = makePicture(pickAFile()) 
vignette = makePicture(pickAFile())
 addVignette(inputPic, vignette) 
def addVignette(inputPic, vignette): 
if getWidth(inputPic) == getWidth(vignette) and getHeight(inputPic) == getHeight(vignette):
  explore(inputPic)
  explore(vignette)
  px1 = getPixels(inputPic)
  px2 = getPixels(vignette) 
 for px in getPixels(inputPic): 
 x = getX(px)
  y = getY(px)
  px2 = getPixelAt(vignette, x, y)
  x2 = getX(px2)
  y2 = getY(px2)
  r1 = getRed(px)
  r2 = getRed(px2)
  g1 = getGreen(px)
  g2 = getGreen(px2)
  b1 = getBlue(px)
  b2 = getBlue(px2)
  newR = (r1-r2+104)
  newG = (g1-g2+88)
  newB = (b1-b2+48)
  newC = makeColor(newR, newG, newB)
  setColor(px, newC)
 explore(inputPic)
 folder = pickAFolder()
 filename = requestString("enter file name: ")
 path = folder+filename+".jpg" 
 writePictureTo(inputPic, path)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqW7K.jpg

picture 1 is what the image needs to be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtS4U.jpg

picture 2 is my image i get at the end of my coding

Any help to get me in the right direction would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After absolutely getting this wrong the first 3 times I worked it out with the help of my little friend the modules operator.

```
def addVignette(inputPic, vignette):
  # Create empty canvas
  canvas = makeEmptyPicture(getWidth(inputPic), getHeight(inputPic))

  for x in range(0, getWidth(inputPic)):
    for y in range(0, getHeight(inputPic)):
      px = getPixel(canvas, x, y)
      inputPixel = getPixel(inputPic, x, y)
      vignettePixel = getPixel(vignette, x, y)

      # Make a new color from those values
      newColor = getNewColorValues(inputPixel, vignettePixel)

      # Assign this new color to the current pixel of the input image
      setColor(px, newColor)

  explore(canvas)

def getNewColorValues(inputPixel, vignettePixel):

  inputRed = getRed(inputPixel)
  vignetteRed = getRed(vignettePixel)
  inputGreen = getGreen(inputPixel)
  vignetteGreen = getGreen(vignettePixel)
  inputBlue = getBlue(inputPixel)
  vignetteBlue = getBlue(vignettePixel)

  newR = inputRed - (255 % vignetteRed) / 3
  newG = inputGreen - (255 % vignetteGreen) / 3
  newB = inputBlue - (255 % vignetteBlue) / 3

  newC = makeColor(newR, newG, newB)
  return newC
```

Comment: thanks @super_mario3d,
its not quite what i was looking for but i'll post up the two images i have to use. the two pictures posted in my original post the first picture is what i need my picture to look like as the end product and the other was my image i got as the end result.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ML00d.jpg

http://i.stack.imgur.com/yVUqN.jpg

these are the images i need to use

Comment: sorry i should been a bit more specific on what the end result needed to be

Comment: @Master_Cdawgg just updated my answer. I think this should be what you are after. Please don't forget to mark this as the correct if it's what you are after.

Comment: its closer to what need basically what need to do is combine the two images i posted in the comment section and then i need to change the pixels of all the corners to be slightly darker like shown in the first link of my question. 

i need to use RGB values but every time i implement the values i alter the entire image instead of only the corners as shown in the first image link of my question i may need to use range but i'm not quite sure exactly how to go able it.

thanks again for your help so far @super_mario3d

Comment: the end result has to be the first link of my question which is what i'm having difficulty getting around unfortunately.

Comment: Lol I hope this is what you are after because I won't have any hair left after this.

Comment: sorry @super_mario3d for making you feel this way, the image doesnt require a oval at all its basically making the edges look faded towards the edges which is essentially making the colors around the edges slightly darker like shown in picture1 of question,

sorry i'm really bad at explaining things forgive my way of explaining things.

Comment: Lol it's all good, I just had to get my head around it. I also have trouble explaining things so I know how you feel. Anyway please see my updated answer and let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: you legend its almost perfect i'll do some tweaking of my own definitely rep for your solution :)

i'll post up the end result but serious you are a miracle worker i can finally understand this a lot better with your explaination Thanks @super_mario3d

if i could rep you i definitely would i unfortunately dont have enough rep to rep anyone else

Comment: i can't believe i didn't think to use getNewColorValues, i guess it slipped my mind... its always better to get someone to look over code to see where things go wrong.... i was about to give up on trying to get this code done i was looking over my code and trying different ways to re access our possibilities for a good 4 hours yesterday only to fail every time.

Comment: i basically have the same code but decided in the end to divide each color in newRed(in the brackets of your code by 1.85 then divided by 1.95 outside bracket, newGreen same again but divided by 1.56 and 1.56 and finally newBlue by 1.16 and 1.16 once that was done i came to the conclusion which wasn't quite correct but almost exactly what i want the image to look like...
unfortunately when i was trying to use the function writePictureTo i got an error the coding i tried to use was as follows'code' folder=pickAFolder()
filename=requestString("enter file name: ")

writePictureTo(inputPic,path)

Comment: Sorry having trouble understanding what's wrong could please create a new question with the code that's not working, the error you get on console and the output you are expecting.

Comment: i had the wrong idea, i don't need to modify the vignette image at all i have to add the vignette effect to the CGI picture i postage in the comments section. the images have to be the same size which i have scaled them to 500px-333px, the end result i am trying to do is combine the vignette picture and the CGI picture because the vignette images RGB values are darker towards the edges i need to multiply the original images corresponding pixels by the smaller numbers towards the edges, should make the picture have a darker frame around the edges of the original picture. sorry @super_mario3d

Comment: i've added a new question@super_mario3d